# Timer not fireing on interval

Tags: c#, timer

I have a problem that min timer event is not fired when it should be, I set it to an interval of 500ms, but as I can see in my logg, this doesn't work as intended. I want the code to excecute when wait 0.5 seconds then start executing again!

```
    public void initilize_Rfid()
    {
        _timerComm = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
        _timerComm.Elapsed += CommTimerEvent;
        _timerComm.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void CommTimerEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _timerComm.Enabled = false;
            Logg("Inside CommTimerEvent " + _name);

            //TALKING TO A SERIALPORT AND DETERMENATING IF TO CONTINUE WITH THE TIMER

            if ((_continueTimer)
            {
                _timerComm.Enabled = true;
               Logg("Re-activating timer " + _name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Logg(ex.ToString()); }
    }
```

I can see the text "Inisde ComTimerEvent TEST1", and then about 0.8 seconds later I get my "Re-activating timer TEST1". That is all just fine. But after this I get a up to 3 seconds delay until the timer fires again... Can I prevent this in some way?

Comment: `System.Timers.Timer` it has an `AutoReset` property. Set this to false and the timer will only run once. Then, in the timer method, start it again like you do. This way you don't need to stop/start the timer all the time.

Comment: Ok, but would that solve my problem? Since the problem is that the timer is not trigged at the right time even thou I set it to enable...

Comment: You can be sure the timer is stopped when the event handler is entered. You don't need to care about stopping it. The overhead of stopping/starting may influence the timer's behaviour. However, I've never ever noticed such problems when using `System.Timers.Timer`. Are you sure that you're not doing anything else after starting the timer? Are you sure that you understood that `System.Timers.Timer` events run in a different thread than the UI thread (exceptions might slow things down)?

Comment: I understand that it's a different thread, but I have no UI interaction in the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can Use DispatcherTimer. The following code will help you to fire a method for every 5 seconds.

```
DispatcherTimer LabelTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                        LabelTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                        LabelTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TaskTimer_Tick_THROW);
```

Comment: This acctually did what I asked for, with this code it's triggered 0.5 seconds after I restart my timer!

Comment: Glad, It works for you!! you can accept the answer so that It would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing :

```
 _timerComm.Start();
```

this will start the timer. If you put it like this:

```
public void initilize_Rfid()
{
    _timerComm = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
    _timerComm.Elapsed += CommTimerEvent;
    _timerComm.Enabled = true;
    _timerComm.Start();
}
```

your code should work if you call this method.

Comment: The `Enabled = true` is equivalent.